# how to deploy windows form app that runs an existing exe's without exe's source code

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have an windows-form application that runs an existing exe's i don't have the source code for other exe's.

how can i deploy this app using Click Once deployment.

Are there any alternatives or other deployment techniques other than click once deployment?

thanks is advance kindly reply soon.

Answer (score 0):

I would add that exe as an embedded resource in my .NET assembly and on first run I will extract it on the harddisk. Take a look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9159/Working-with-Embedded-Data)

Comment: i think you misunderstood my question. i like to publish my exe on web and run exe's through web browser. no downloading for client.